# How to construct a Facebook post URL from the post id?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to construct a permalink for objects returned by Facebook's new Graph API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103051/how-to-construct-a-permalink-for-objects-returned-by-facebooks-new-graph-api)

The Facebook open graph API allows a public search, e.g.

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=watermelon

The results returned may be statuses, videos, links, photos (and others?).

Each has a post id, e.g.

```
100000973592583_149321401769498
```

I wish to construct a URL to the post.  For statuses, this seems to work:

http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100000973592583&v=wall&story_fbid=149321401769498

However, for a link (or video or photo), that often works, but sometimes does not.  For example, a link with id

```
45430244790_127287890653212
```

needed

http://www.facebook.com/posted.php?id=45430244790&share_id=127287890653212&comments=1#s127287890653212

Does someone have experience creating bulletproof links?  Are there any docs on it?

**Edit**: Suppose I know the type as well (video, post, photo, link, ..)

Answer (score 7):

Following FQL:

```sql
SELECT permalink
FROM stream
WHERE post_id="45430244790_127287890653212"
```

would return:

```sql
[
  {
    "permalink": "http://www.facebook.com/posted.php?id=45430244790&share_id=127287890653212&comments=1#s127287890653212"
  }
]
```

Comment: I appreciate this answer, but is there no way to construct the URL without another call to facebook for every post?

Comment: @dfrankow you can make one big group call instead of many single calls (use `where post_in in (1,2,3...)`). Other than that I don't know a better solution, sorry.

Comment: As of now, the FQL is deprecated for the api v2.1