# facebook - get url of existing comment

Tags: facebook, url, comments

I am using facebook comments on many pages/servers for one FB application.

Is any options how to find url of added comment (I need to distinguish that each of comment belongs to certain page)?

I haven't find anything like that in management tool for comments.

Thx. Sam.

Comment: To construct URL

http://stackoverflow.com/q/3689040/3824370

Comment: One way of working this out is to watch the url's facebooks own notification ball is linking to.