# Get permalink to a post published on user's wall

Tags: facebook, dialog, fbml

Using Facebook dialogs, app users can share stories. I wish to be able to construct a permalink to the published story and offer as link to view the post. What we receive in response is the post_id, which alone doesn't look sufficient.

Would it possible to construct a permalink based alone on the post_id, if not, what other approach are possible?

Thanks a ton for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it in the response when you access the post via its ID in the API?
There should be a permalink in there in the `actions` object which you can direct the user to for them to like/comment on the new post

Comment: Igy, thanks for the pointer. I was able to construct permalink to the post following [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5081859/1520518).

Answer (score 12):

You can constuct a link to the original posts with the post_id in the URL with this pattern:

```
http://www.facebook.com/7683938373/posts/7938393003
```

where the `post_id` is `7683938373_7938393003`. (This is a made up post_id)

Just as a note: You can also access a permalink field from the stream table.

Johnny